# REACTJS: TypeError: posts.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, typeerror

I know there are a lot of questions about this but after being for one hour trying to solve it I couldn't.

I am using Reducer hook And Context Hook (just FYI) in my app and on a Postlist Component, when I try to map the posts array from my db.json, gives me this error:**TypeError: posts.map is not a function** I would really appreciate your help.

PostList.js

```
    import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
    import { StateContext } from '../contexts'
    import Post from './Post'

export default function PostList () {

    const { state } = useContext(StateContext)
    const { posts } = state 

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                {posts && posts.map((p, i) =>  <Post {...p}
                key={'post-' + i}/>)}

            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

db.json (fragment)

```
 {
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": "react-hooks",
          "title": "React Hooks",
          "content": "The greatest thing since sliced bread!",
          "author": "Daniel Bugl"
        },
        {
          "id": "react-fragments",
          "title": "Using React Fragments",
          "content": "Keeping the DOM tree clean!",
          "author": "Daniel Bugl"
        },
        {
          "title": "Esto es un post",
          "content": "HOla",
          "author": "marianods",
          "id": "citi6O7"
        },
        {
          "title": "Hol",
          "content": "hola\n",
          "author": "hola",
          "id": "JnK9FCD"
        }
      ],
```

contexts.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
    primaryColor: 'deepskyblue',
    secondaryColor: 'coral'
})

export const StateContext = React.createContext({
    state: {},
    dispatch: () => {}
})
```

[image]

Let me know if you need more assets to analyze.

Comment: can you add contexts file code here?

Comment: can you add your code snippet to code sandbox.

Comment: Just posted my context.js snippet. thanks.

Comment: The error clearly states that posts is not an Array. Could you check by debugging what you're getting in posts that you're using inside render()?

Comment: try console.log(posts) to see it's value/

Comment: Just Posted it's fetching my four array elements empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wave-2dqwp?file=/src/contexts.js) Hope this will answer your problem.

you have missed passing posts in your context state.

```
import React from "react";
import { posts } from "./db.json";

export const StateContext = React.createContext({
  state: {
    posts
  },
  dispatch: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Hi Vipin, after trying your fix I was having the same error.Suddenly, don't ask me how, I remember I used the reversed method in app.js (posts.data.reverse()) but without the ().

Now the problem is that I am having this error:

react-dom.development.js:13413 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username, password, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I just realized re reading all the cod that I made to silly mistake in the syntaxis. I forgot the '/' before login and '.username' after 'username:user.data[0]'. Now I can go to sleep.

```
const [user, login] =useResource((username, password) =>({
        url:`/login/${encodeURI(username)}/${encodeURI(password)}`,
        method: 'get'
    }))

    useEffect(() => {
        if(user && user.data) {
            if (user.data.length > 0) {
                setLoginFailed(false)
                dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', username:user.data[0].username})
            } else {
                setLoginFailed(true)
            }
            if(user && user.error) {
                setLoginFailed(true)
            }
        }
    }, [user])
```